# Optical emission seen in Relativistic Jets from Quasars

Tags: relativistic-jets, quasars

[image: Optical image of 3C273. Image courtesy: arXiv.]

So, I came across a very exciting paper on [arXiv today](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2402.09505.pdf). Here, they talk about the Hubble Space Telescope (HST) imaging of the host galaxy of the very first known quasar- 3C 273. My question is related to the 'tail' seen in the current and earlier optical images of this object.

From my understanding, synchrotron emission is responsible for emissions coming from the powerful jets in active galactic nuclei (AGN), which is basically the tail I am talking about. I also understand it is not limited to the radio spectrum; it can span a broad range of wavelengths, including optical and UV.  However, I am curious about the specific conditions leading to the jet emission in the optical regime, specifically for [3C 273](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3C_273), where we see a very prominent jet in the optical images.

1. Since the particles are in almost relativistic motion inside the jet and the optical emissions would require larger Synchrotron cooling timescales, we should not have optical emissions from the jets as these electrons will lag behind. Am I missing something here?
2. I was also reading that the electrons responsible for optical synchrotron emission may be produced locally, maybe in the knots of the jet itself. But in that case, we should be seeing blobs of emission in the optical images of jets, not a streak, right?